# Error: expected ';' before the closing parenthesis for loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Okay, so I am still new to C++. I've tried multiple different solutions and cant get this to work.

```
for(i = 0, i < counter,i++){
    cout<<"Please enter a score: \n";
    cin>>score[i];
    sum += score[i];
}
```

This is the error I'm getting: 
cpp(22): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'

Why does it want me to put a semicolon in the for loop. Did I not write it correctly? The rest of the code is fine. I've done this in it's own program and it still gives me this error.

Comment: You want ; not , because that's the syntax for a for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop syntax is wrong.

```
for(i = 0, i < counter,i++){
```

should be

```
for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
```

Answer (score 4):

It's:

```
for (a ; b ; c) ...
```

not

```
for (a, b, c) ...
```

Change your `,` to `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, C++ syntax for "for" loop requires the given syntax:

```
for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; UPDATION){
//your statements;
}
```

Your program would run just fine with these minor changes(';' instead of ','):

```
for(i = 0; i < counter;i++){
cout<<"Please enter a score: \n";
cin>>score[i];
sum += score[i];
}
```